# Event firing multiple times in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

So, I wrote a function that using which the user can upload multiple files.

```
<input multiple type="file" id="inputFile" ref="fileSelect" @click="uploadfiles"/>

uploadfiles(){     
    'use strict'
  const inputFile = document.getElementById('inputFile')

  console.log(inputFile)
  inputFile!.addEventListener('change',async e => {
    const files  = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files
    const reader = new FileReader()
    console.log(files)
    console.log(reader)
    // New set of results each time.
    this.results.splice(0)

    for (const file of files!){
      if(file["type"] == "application/json"){
      this.results.push(await this.readjsonfile(reader, file))}
      else if(file["type"]=="text/csv"){
        this.results.push(await this.readcsvfile(reader, file))
      }
      
      }

    })}
```

Now when I upload a file for the 1st time it works fine, but when I click on the `choose files` button again to upload another file, it uploads that file twice.
I think the problem is that when I click again on `choose files` I "activate" the `uploadfiles` function again, which causes the `Event Listener` to fire twice, but I am not sure how to do it any other way.
I am new to JavaScript and vuejs, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks to @Daniel I finally ended up figuring out how to fix this.
My final code is

```
<input multiple type="file" id="inputFile" ref="fileSelect" @change="uploadfiles"/>
```

```
uploadfiles(event){     
    'use strict'
    console.log(event)
    //console.log(event.target.files)
    const q = [event.target.files]
    q.forEach(async w => {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      this.results=[]
      for(const file of w){
        if(file["type"] == "application/json"){
      this.results.push(await this.readjsonfile(reader, file))}
      else if(file["type"]=="text/csv"){
        this.results.push(await this.readcsvfile(reader, file))
      }
      }
    })
    console.log(this.results)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you're adding `inputFile!.addEventListener` every time the user clicks on the input form

Instead, if you were to use `@change`, instead of `@click`, that should not be happening any more.

example:

```html
<script setup>
  import {ref} from "vue"
  let files = ref([])
  function uploadfiles(event){
    files.value.splice(0);
    [...event.target.files].forEach(async file => {
      // do the logic here
      files.value.push(file)
    })
  }
</script>

<template>
  <input multiple type="file" id="inputFile" ref="fileSelect" @change="uploadfiles"/>
  <pre>{{files}}</pre>
</template>
```

[SFC playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpNUctuwyAQ/JUVJ0dqoOfUidpD+wM9xjlQsraJMCBYUkWW/72AkyonLzPj2cfM7MN7fk3IdqyNKmhPEJGSP3QWQE/eBYI5YL9AH9wEHcvajhXSIEGvDUbYQxY0x9OmwH2yirSzkLxx8lwVDV7R0mYufFYUiF+lScijN1ph87p5W7kj57yKOckwIPEqPvHehU+pxkbGm1XVAfYHuBsCCAFnBzQiGDdoBSMGfHDP7XyKY1OAOirAUr9LZ1uxLp/Xzg/CyRtJWI/QausTwZQMaZ/70s3jvmPFpWOgz7muiq8VyKe4s99oUFGG3tUo7VB+erpJx8Rq7wMe5rliy9KK8izz/M/AXtiaw3aSnl+iszmrunluXInstXvc4h7QLhcjkY87IWKvSsKXyF0YRK54SJb0hBzjtP0J7jdiyMZrrPkYC1v+AN87tvE=)

Comment: I have one more doubt, how should I read the file initially I was reading ```const inputFile = document.getElementById('inputFile')``` but this gives an error in your line ```files.value.splice(0);``` as ```Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'```, I tried reading as ```const inputFile = (this.$refs.fileSelect as HTMLInputElement).files``` again I got an error in the line ```files.value.splice(0);``` . Also ```[...event.target.files]``` shows that [...event] is depreceated. [link]https://jsfiddle.net/Harsh2207/om5wbjcv/7/.
I'll be grateful if you could let me know my mistake.

Comment: a few things to note...  you are using class API (my example uses Composition) no need to use `ref([])` if you have value defined in `data`  and it was meant to work as `results`, so you don't really need to define it at all and the `files.value.splice(0)` is not needed because you are doing `this.results.splice(0)`

Comment: you also don't need ` document.getElementById('inputFile')` because the `event.target.files` gives you the list of selected files, and adding a nested `const files  = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files` inside that just doesn't make sense, you're already looping through the files, so you'd just end up processing each file multiple time s (`n^2` specifically)

Comment: but ```[...event.target.files]``` is depreciated and apart from the ```value``` error, another error is in ```forEach``` as ```forEach does not exisit on string```.

Comment: you can use  `for (const file of event.target.files)` instead of `[...event.target.files].forEach` if you like